How to scrape infinite scroll web ite if requests are identical?
I am trying to extract data from Behance using the API, an infinite scroll site. As you scroll, new products and requests will start to appear. Now I know which requests contains the data of the products but the problem is that those requests are identical. I am unable to write a for loop to automatically create a new request and extract the data. Below is the request (cURL converted to Python request):
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    '^cookie': 'gk_suid=27885050; gki=disable_graphql_metrics_to_timestream: false, test_cross_auth: false, feature_search_gk_debug: false, list_keyboard_nav: false, feature_image_search_with_project_title: false, updated_user_search_cards: false, feature_profile_work_sticky_hire_cta: false,; bcp=1f130e91-c6c8-47e5-99cf-673dad470fd3; dialog_dismissals=following_tags_ftux_tooltip; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2024-05-01T15:07:33.232Z; OptanonConsent=groups=C0001^%^3A1^%^2CC0002^%^3A1^%^2CC0003^%^3A1^%^2CC0004^%^3A1; kndctr_9E1005A551ED61CA0A490D45_AdobeOrg_identity=CiYxMjA1MjMzODY3NTc5NDA5OTM5MTM5NDY3MzM4NDQ5NzQxMjYyOFITCM-vyaXzMRABGAEqBElSTDEwAPABz6_JpfMx; kndctr_9E1005A551ED61CA0A490D45_AdobeOrg_consent=general=in; AMCV_9E1005A551ED61CA0A490D45^%^40AdobeOrg=MCMID^|12052338675794099391394673384497412628; _cs_mk_aa=0.31804581114055797_1714585870715; gpv=behance.net:search:projects; kndctr_9E1005A551ED61CA0A490D45_AdobeOrg_cluster=irl1^',
    'origin': 'https://www.behance.net',
    'priority': 'u=1, i',
    'referer': 'https://www.behance.net/',
    '^sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Chromium^\\^;v=^\\^124^\\^, ^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    '^sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^^',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-bcp': '1f130e91-c6c8-47e5-99cf-673dad470fd3',
    'x-newrelic-id': 'VgUFVldbGwsFU1BRDwUBVw==',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = '^^{^\\^query^\\^:^\\^^\\^\\n'

response = requests.post('https://www.behance.net/v3/graphql', headers=headers, data=data)

The request named 'graphql' is what I need, and every time I scroll to the bottom, the same request name will appear and some of which does not contain the data:

Any hint how to distinguish between the two requests?

You can use this example how to make POST request to get more pages:
import base64

import requests


def encode(s):
    encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(s.encode())
    encoded_string = encoded_bytes.decode()
    return encoded_string


payload = {
    "query": "\n      query GetProjectSearchResults($query: query, $filter: SearchResultFilter, $first: Int!, $after: String) {\n        search(query: $query, type: PROJECT, filter: $filter, first: $first, after: $after) {\n          pageInfo {\n            hasNextPage\n            endCursor\n          }\n          nodes {\n            ... on Project {\n              __typename\n              ...projectSearchFields\n            }\n          }\n          metaContent {\n            totalEntityCount\n            toolCard {\n              cta {\n                text\n                url\n              }\n              description\n              links {\n                text\n                url\n                type\n              }\n              slug\n              title\n            }\n            schoolCard {\n              cta {\n                text\n                url\n              }\n              description\n              slug\n            }\n            csam {\n              isCSAMViolation\n              description\n              helpResource\n              reportingOption\n            }\n            followableTag {\n              isFollowing\n              tag {\n                id\n                title\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n\n      \n  fragment projectSearchFields on Project {\n    id\n    colors {\n      r\n      g\n      b\n    }\n    isMatureReviewSubmitted\n    linkedAssetsCount\n    name\n    premium\n    isPrivate\n    publishedOn\n    isFounder\n    isFeatured\n    modifiedOn\n    canBeAddedToMoodboard\n    adminFlags {\n      mature_lock\n      privacy_lock\n      dmca_lock\n      flagged_lock\n      privacy_violation_lock\n      trademark_lock\n      spam_lock\n      eu_ip_lock\n    }\n    features {\n      featuredOn\n      url\n      name\n      ribbon {\n        image\n        image2x\n        image3x\n      }\n    }\n    slug\n    stats {\n      views {\n        all\n      }\n      appreciations {\n        all\n      }\n      comments {\n        all\n      }\n    }\n    url\n    fields {\n      label\n    }\n    linkedAssets {\n      ...sourceLinkFields\n    }\n    sourceFiles {\n      ...sourceFileWithCoverFields\n    }\n    matureAccess\n    hasMatureContent\n    owners {\n      ...OwnerFields\n      images {\n        size_50 {\n          url\n        }\n        size_100 {\n          url\n        }\n        size_115 {\n          url\n        }\n        size_138 {\n          url\n        }\n        size_230 {\n          url\n        }\n        size_276 {\n          url\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    covers {\n      size_original {\n        url\n      }\n      size_max_808 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_808 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_404 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_202 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_230 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_115 {\n        url\n      }\n      size_original_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_max_808_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_808_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_404_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_202_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_230_webp {\n        url\n      }\n      size_115_webp {\n        url\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  \n  fragment sourceFileWithCoverFields on SourceFile {\n    __typename\n    sourceFileId\n    projectId\n    userId\n    title\n    assetId\n    renditionUrl\n    mimeType\n    size\n    category\n    licenseType\n    unitAmount\n    currency\n    tier\n    hidden\n    extension\n    hasUserPurchased\n    description\n    cover {\n      coverUrl\n      coverX\n      coverY\n      coverScale\n    }\n  }\n\n  \n  fragment sourceLinkFields on LinkedAsset {\n    __typename\n    name\n    premium\n    url\n    category\n    licenseType\n  }\n\n  \n  fragment OwnerFields on User {\n    displayName\n    hasPremiumAccess\n    id\n    isFollowing\n    isProfileOwner\n    location\n    locationUrl\n    url\n    username\n    isMessageButtonVisible\n    availabilityInfo {\n      availabilityTimeline\n      isAvailableFullTime\n      isAvailableFreelance\n      hiringTimeline {\n        key\n        label\n      }\n    }\n    creatorPro {\n      isActive\n      initialSubscriptionDate\n    }\n  }\n\n\n    ",
    "variables": {"after": "NDg=", "filter": {}, "first": 48},
}

url = "https://www.behance.net/v3/graphql"

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-BCP": "96ee8700-3ce5-4445-96b2-ab0e1a76a63a",
}


cookies = {
    "bcp": "96ee8700-3ce5-4445-96b2-ab0e1a76a63a",
}

for page in range(0, 4):   # <-- increase number of pages here
    payload["variables"]["after"] = encode(str(page * 48))

    data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, json=payload).json()

    # for example print names:
    for n in data["data"]["search"]["nodes"]:
        print(n["name"])

    print("-" * 80)

Prints:

...

Modern Expo - animated film
Wavelink-1
Elysium
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORMA FURNITURE
Le Mochi Glacé
2024 국민의 선택
pfp avatars collection
Illustrations for interactive books
NUMBERS ARE NOT AN OPINION

...


thanks for the code. It is working. But I am not familiar with making POST requests as you did. Your answer btw pointed me to learn this trick.
